# Nested fragment: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I just discovered a permanent crash on my Pixel simulator with API 24.
My real device, and some other simulator don't have this error.

What I'm doing is the following: In a fragment I try to add another fragment, using this code:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val fragmentTransaction = requireFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    val fragment = ComposableTableReportFragment.newInstance(null)
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.tableContainer, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

This results in the following crash at the launch of my app.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.pokeranalytics.android, PID: 20332
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
        at net.pokeranalytics.android.ui.fragment.StatisticsFragment.initUI(StatisticsFragment.kt:71)
        at net.pokeranalytics.android.ui.fragment.StatisticsFragment.onViewCreated(StatisticsFragment.kt:62)
```

I've tried various things as seen on SO, as the crash is pretty frequent, but it seems every case is unique and didn't found a solution for mine. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 5):

Try switching to -

```
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
```